# Use of articles before introducing a list

Tags: sentence-construction, american-english, sentence-structure

Use of articles in the English Language is always confusing to me. I know some general rules regarding the use of articles, but I am having trouble applying them.

My question is: should I use an article before introducing a list in a sentence?

> Experience allows people to acquire knowledge based on the observation
>   rather than **[the]** theory, intuition, or innate idea.

I am not sure if "the" is needed here.

My guess is that "the" is not needed because I am not referring to a specific theory or idea. However, "observation" is preceded by "the", does it mean that "the" is also needed before "theory"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sense of using **the** is correct, it is not a **specific** theory, intuition, or innate idea.

Acquiring knowledge is based **many different observations**, so in the same way as theory

> Experience allows people to acquire knowledge based on observation rather than theory, intuition, or innate idea.
>
> Experience allows people to acquire knowledge based on observation**s** rather than theorie**s**, intuition, or innate idea**s**.

the plurals can also be used for countables

Answer (score 2):

I would not use articles before general principles (observations, theories, intuition, or ideas). This statement discusses the topic in general, not a specific topic. So:

> Experience allows people to acquire knowledge based on observation rather than (on) theory, intuition, or innate idea.

"observation" does not need an article in this example.

Comment: Thank you. Now I think I've gained a better understanding of when to use articles